# Accessing data from a vue component that houses only a class script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue component (A) with a HTML canvas. It also passes data (using provider() and inject) to a nested component (B) so that component B can write to it.

Component B is used to draw on the canvas that is located in component (A).

The issue is component B is importing a `Class.vue`.

```
import {ImageMaker} from './Class'
```

This is accessed with `image = new ImageMaker()` and `image.draw2()` on component B

Now, the `Class.vue` looks like this:

```
<script>
    Class ImageMaker{
        constructor(a,b,src){
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b
            this.src= src
        }
    
        draw(){
            ...
        }
    
        draw2(){
            ctx.drawImage(...)
        }
    }
    
    export default{
        ImageMaker
    }
</script>
```

`ctx` is set in a `render()` property in component B (PS: I have tested it... I can write to the canvas with that)

Question:

1. How can Class.vue access the ctx in the ImageMaker Class?
   I have tried using props but not working since it's not the traditional vue template
2. I am fairly new to vue, is there no way to use Classes with constructors on any vue properties? I nested the Class.vue content in the `method(), mounted()` properties but wasn't working too.

EDIT:
Component B:

```
export default{
    inject: ['provider'],

    data(){
        return {
            ...
        }
    },

    render(){
        if(!this.provider.context) return;
        const ctx = this.provider.context;

        ctx.drawTxt(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Class.vue` doesn't need to be a vue file format. You can import any js file inside the script tag of a vue component.

Comment: Why do you create `ImageMaker` in a `.vue` file? That file extension is intended for Vue SFCs, and `ImageMaker` does not appear to be a component.

Comment: @tony19 Yes. I am aware. I can as well rename it to a .js extension and the question still remains the same. I was on the around around movement.